# Good example of a walk-through of the FCI algorithm to ensure all steps are done

Tags: references, causality, graphical-model, causal-diagram

The FCI algorithm is a common algorithm used for learning a Markov equivalence class of causal graphs from observational data.

I am wondering if there are any good examples that walk through a causal graph and applications of each of its steps along the way to orient the graph.